# Sharing protobufs between Play apps

Tags: java, playframework, protocol-buffers

In migrating a project to Play! Framework, the one unresolved dependency is a common protocol buffer jar shared by several servers. The project now consists of several Maven modules; one of them being the generated Java source from the .proto files. Whenever we build one of the servers, it generates the proto module jar as a dependency, so we always have up-to-date protobufs.

I'm not sure how best to do this in Play. Here are a couple ideas I have, each with limitations:

1. Bring in a jar using `play deps` from a maven repo. This would be the easiest to set up, but would require pushing a new jar and syncing deps for each proto change, which would be a pain. Also, it would be hard for two people to work on their own proto changes at the same time.
2. Make a module whose sole job is to use ant and protoc to compile the protos and export them in a jar. The problem with this is that (I think) we would have to manually call `play build-module` in the module for any protobuf changes.

What I would really like is a way to have each app automatically compile the protos every build (it doesn't have to be hot-swappable, but that would be a bonus). Is there any way to make this happen?